# remove azure storage account with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I was looking a way to delete azure storage account using powershell.

There are powershell command to remove blob,container,table,queue, filed, directory. But I don't see any way to remove/delete azure storage account using powershell.

Through portal I can do it, but need to do it through powershell.

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.storage/v1.2.0/remove-azurermstorageaccount) or [Remove-AzureStorageAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.service/v2.1.0/remove-azurestorageaccount) depending on the deployment model you are using?

To find those you can always use `Get-Command remove-azure*storage*`

Comment: Also, the generic Remove-AzureRmResource cmdlet will work for any resource as some don't have explicit remove commands.

Answer (score -1):

This article may help you -> [scroll down to- To remove the whole storage account](http://wastedcoder.com/azure/managing-azure-storage-accounts-with-powershell)

This is the powershell command-

```
Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name resourceGrouptest
```

where resourceGrouptest is the name of the resource group.
you also need to first login into your account using-

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```